# Xpath to determine checkbox "checked" attribute in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

How to determine if a checkbox is check or not through xpath

Currently I am trying :

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='true')]
```

I have multiple checkboxes with same ids so I have to select the next checkbox which is not selected/checked.

Specifically I need this for Selenium IDE

**Edit**
what I actually need is sth like :

```
|storeXpathCount | //input[@name='xyz' and @checked='checked'] | is_checked |
```

if checkbox 'xyz' is checked , is_checked value should be 1 else 0

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here `stnewrecord` is class of check-box.
Script will store number of check-box, and according to that loop will follow.
It will check whether check-box is checked or not if not it will check else move to next step.

```
xpath=(//input[@class='stnewrecord'])[${i}]
```

This is xpath of check-box. 'i' is position, it will increase on each iteration.

Let me know whether its working for you or not..

Comment: please check my question again

Comment: thanks got it `storeValue | //input[@name='xyz'] | is_checked`  will store "on" or "off" depending on whether checkbox is checked or not

Answer (score 14):

The xpath

```
// Xpath, only works in certain situations
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='xyz']
```

only works if in the HTML source of the checkbox there is an attribute as follows

```
checked="xyz"
```

where the developer is free to replace "xyz" with anything: "true", "checked", "ischecked", ...

So if there is no such attribute, the above mentioned xpath does not work.

While waiting for more insight, you might consider using a CSS selector, which does not depend on such an attribute:

```
// CSS selector, for all checkboxes which are checked
input:checked[type='checkbox']

// CSS selector, for all checkboxes which are not checked
input:not(:checked)[type='checkbox']
```

Note that without

```
[type='checkbox']
```

you will be given also radios :-)

Comment: I think you missed my point ,I need the specific thing with respective to Seleinum IDE

Answer (score 3):

However, there are solution without using css classes and selectors.

Use

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked]
```

or

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and not(@checked)]
```

instead of

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='xyz']
```

Comment: have you tried this in Selenium IDE ? @checked value is 'on' or 'off' its not a boolean !

Comment: I had not tried this in IDE, but I use this expression expression with Selenium extension for PHPUnit. However, I think that xpath engine is the same for both tools. Let me know if you have tried this in IDE.

Comment: yes I have some tests for selenium IDE and it does not return boolean values , instead 'on' , 'off' for @checked attribute

Comment: I'm necroposting here, but as of 2018, this is wrong. (Try it in Chrome browser.)

Answer (score 0):

something like this may works:

```xml
//input[@checked='checked']/following-sibling::*[1][not(@checked='checked')]
```

Comment: `//input[@checked='checked']` not working that is  the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try these one:

```
//*[@type='radio'][@checked='checked']/
//*[@type='radio'][not(@checked='checked')]/
```

Comment: thanks, we are strictly talking in the context of Selenium IDE, in that context its `@checked` attirbutes has 'on' or 'off' value , please read the above answers for the history

Comment: I've tested these in Selenium IDE and it seemed that it was working, but I could be wrong, as I was looking for something similar.