# 'gotoIf' Command is not working in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In my test case i want to check weather a checkbox is already checked or not.

If not checked then i will not proceed else i will proceed.

here is the code

```
  <tr>

             <td>storeValue</td>

           <td>//div[@id='insurance_type_selected']/div[@class='prod_type_list']/p[@class='groupTtl']/label[@for='prod_insurance_types_1']/input[@type='checkbox']/</td>
        <td>val</td>

    </tr>


    <tr>    

         <td>echo</td>
         <td>${val}</td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>gotoIf</td>

        <td>storedVars['val']=='on'</td>

        <td>true</td>
    </tr>
```

During execution  this error is showing

> [info] Executing: |gotoIf | storedVars['val']=='on' | true |
>
> **[error] Unknown command: 'gotoIf'**

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium IDE doesn't support gotoif command, that's why you are getting error `Unknown command: 'gotoIf'`

To use `gotoif` command in selenium IDE, you need to import file. 
You can get that file from [HERE](http://wiki.openqa.org/pages/viewpageattachments.action?pageId=379&metadataLink=true)

You can have a look [HERE](http://radical-qa.blogspot.in/2012/02/selenium-ide_09.html) for reference.

Also have a look on [Xpath to determine checkbox "checked" attribute in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758616/xpath-to-determine-checkbox-checked-attribute/11760025#11760025)

Comment: I downloaded the files to my desktop and unzipped them. after that i opened the selenium ide  and through 

Options > options > selenium core extension 

i uploded  the file goto_sel_ide.js

during executing my test case through ide i got the following error 


[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/Neil/Desktop/New%20folder/goto_sel_ide.js?1348644882283, lineNumber -> 90


Can u please tell me how can i remove this error and what wrong i have done .

Comment: I am using Selenium IDE 1.9.0 version.

Comment: using which file in that?? Use goto_sel_ide.js file only

Comment: This happened to me recently. I found, open of the add-on is missing - Selenium Flow Control. After installing this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (assertChecked(label="prod_insurance_types_1")) {
    assertTrue(False) // this way it would fail and don't proceed
} else {
    // do sth
```

Something like this should work as far as I remeber

Comment: I have used bot If  and if  but in both cases it is showing

 [error] Unknown command: 'If'
  or
  [error] Unknown command: 'if'

can u tell me how to write in selenium ide

Comment: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/automating-boring-tasks-selenium-ide 
 http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl
 read this, maybe this would help

Answer (score 0):

You need the Flow Control plugin, listed on the SeleniumHQ download page: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/#side_plugins

Direct link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/85794/